# Android 6.0 optimizing app 1 of 1 on smart tv

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, smart-tv

I have a TV that runs on android 6.0 and it gives me the optimizing app 1 of 1 message each time I start it, I have to factory reset everytime and it only lasts for a month before ir comes back, any way to fix it once and for all.

Comment: why factory reset? that is just some app refreshing dalvik-cache

Comment: It keeps optimizing for about 30 min everytime i turn on the tv and that's the only way i found to stop it.